# How long did it take the Mugiwara crew to reach Sabaody Archipelago?

Tags: one-piece

After the Mugiwara crew reached the Sabaody Archipelago, they decided to take a "break" for 2 years.

But, before this break, how many month or years did it take for them to reach the Archipelago? How long was it after Luffy was released from the barrel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to this [World Timeline](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/World_Timeline) and [this other one](http://onepiece.wikkii.net/wiki/World_Timeline), in total we're between the 2 and 3 years. In the first chapter, Luffy was 17, now he's 19.

The break took 2 years, but before that we have some months of [Morgan](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Morgan) (first antagonist) then [Captain Kuro](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Kuro), [Don Krieg](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Krieg), [Arlong](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Arlong), etc.

Comment: So it's more or less 2 years and a couple of month from the start to nowadays ?!

Comment: I'd say more than a literal couple. But yeah, not more than three years. :)

Answer (score 1):

*Luffy departed at the age of 17, no info on whether it was on the first month of the year or if it was on his birthday*.

| Event | Period |
| --- | --- |
| Luffy's solo voyage | 1d |
| Alvida arc | 1d |
| Zoro arc | 1d |
| Buggy arc | 1d |
| Usopp arc | 3d |
| Island of Rare Animals | 1d |
| Meeting Yosaku and Johnny | 1d |
| Baratie arc | 4d |
| Nami in flashback with Straw Hats | 1d (ep. 34) |
| Nami arc | 4d |
| Travel | 2d (ep. 45 & 46) |
| Loguetown arc | 1d |
| Travel | 2d |
| Warship Island arc | 2d |
| Twin cape | 1d |
| Travel & Whiskey Peak | 1d |
| Travel | 2d |
| Little Garden arc | 1d |
| Travel | 1d |
| Drum Island arc | 1d (Ep80: Vivi mention Nami's been sick for 3 days. 1st d: Little Garden, 2nd d: Travel, 3rd d: Reach Drum Island) |
| Travel to Arabasta | 7d (after Drum island, Straw Hats headed for Arabasta, and in ep. 78, Vivi mentions that it's not possible to get to Arabasta within a week. Rough guess: 10 days, so 10d-3d=7d) |
| Arabasta arc | 10d |
| Post Arabasta arc | 5d |
| Travel | 1d |
| Goat Island arc | 7d |
| Travel | d |
| Ruluka island arc | d |
| Jaya | 1d |
| Skypiea arc | 6d (Apparently in One Piece Fandom Wiper's section, Straw Hats were partying for several days before departing, so I'll just add 3d on top of the 3d shown in the anime) |
| Navarone arc | 2d |
| LRLL arc | 1d |
| Travel | 1d |
| Ocean's dream arc | 2d |
| Travel | 3d (In fandom, it said Foxy's Return arc took place "sometime after" Ocean's Dream arc, so I'll just assume they've been traveling for 3d) |
| Foxy's Return arc | 1d |
| Encounter with Aokiji | 1d |
| Rest | 4d |
| Travel | 2d (3rd day arrive on Water 7) |
| Water Seven arc | 2d |
| Enies Lobby arc | 1d |
| Post-Enies lobby arc | 4d (Luffy&Zoro reunite with Coby on the 2nd day) |
| Travel | 2d (At the start of the Ice Hunter arc, the crew is still in the middle of talking and praising how awesome their new ship is. So 2d is about right) |
| Ice Hunter arc | 2d |
| Travel | 3d (In the Fandom Thriller Bark's section, it said "a few days" after Water 7, but unlike in the Ice Hunter arc, the crew no longer discusses much about Sunny. The excitement of getting a new ship has died down) |
| Thriller Bark arc | 5d |
| Travel | 1d |
| Spa Island arc | 4d (the arc is 1d, and in Fandom Spa Island section, it mentions "A few days later", so I'll add 3d travel on top of the 1d) |
| Rest | 2d |
| Travel | 1d |
| Sabaody arc | 1d |
| Kuma Express Fast & Comfortable | 3d |
| Amazon Lily arc | 1d |
| Impel Down & Marineford arc | 6d (in ep410, Momonga mentions the date/day of execution. Ep. 416 Elder Nyon confirmed "in a week, which is six days from today") |
| Ep. 411 | Luffy's Straw Hat became bigger |
| Post-war arc | 14d + 7d (Amazon Lily to Marineford) + 7d (Marineford to Ruskaina) |
| **Total** | **154 days** |

In the Warship Island arc, Nami shown us on the map the distance of their travel and how many days it took to reach said distance. Apparently, Straw Hats has been traveling for 2d after they left Loguetown, yet they're still far away from reaching the RedLine/Reverse Mountain. The journey from one island to another always took almost a week, but unless the crew or the episode mentions it directly, I'll just assume it took them 1d instead. And I'll also count it as 1d for every time Nami changes her clothes.

Answer (score 0):

When they reach the Red Line, the halfway point on the Grand Line, the crew celebrate and comment on what a year it had been. This is just before the Sabaody Archipelago Arc. So with the two year break, it is a little over 3 years in total.

This information is from the manga, not sure if they mentioned it in then anime.

Comment: Before the break, how many months/years?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the best One Piece timeline](https://thelibraryofohara.com/the-one-piece-timeline/) I've seen so far, it took Luffy and his crew something like 70 days, give or take like 20 days, from the time he left his barrel to the time he arrived at Sabaody Archipelago.